# Retrieving PrinterJob attributes

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt

I am using java awt PrinterJob to show a Print Dialog and submit a job to print. I would like to read the attributes selected by the user from the dialog before the job is submitted, but I see that 'attributes' is a protected variable, so not sure how I can access it. I need to run some analysis on the print job being submitted. Is there a workaround here?

Comment: This is the code I am using. PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); boolean ok  = job.printDialog; After job attributes are selected from the print dialog, I would like to read and analyze the attributes.

Comment: what if we dont use printdialog? can we get the number of printed copies using java.....? @curie

Answer (score 0):

Instead of method [`PrinterJob.printDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#printDialog--)
you should use method [`PrinterJob.printDialog(PrintRequestAttributeSet)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#printDialog-javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet-).
In the supplied [`PrintRequestAttributeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet.html)
you will receive all the attributes as chosen by the user in the print dialog.

From this `PrintRequestAttributeSet` you can then

- get all the attributes by calling its `toArray()` method
- or get individual attributes by using the `get(Class<?>)` method
  (use the classes implementing `PrintRequestAttribute` from package
  [`javax.print.attribute.standard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/package-summary.html)
  as keys.)

Then you can change the `PrintRequestAttributeSet` by removing or adding attributes.

And finally you submit the `PrinterJob` by calling its `print()` method.

Example:

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.attribute.Attribute;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    boolean ok = job.printDialog(attributes);

    Attribute[] attributeArray = attributes.toArray();
    for (Attribute a : attributeArray) {
        System.out.println(a.getName() + ": " + a);
    }

    System.out.println();

    Attribute copies = attributes.get(Copies.class);
    Attribute media = attributes.get(Media.class);
    Attribute mediaPrintableArea = attributes.get(MediaPrintableArea.class);
    Attribute mediaTray = attributes.get(MediaTray.class);
    Attribute orientationRequested = attributes.get(OrientationRequested.class);
    Attribute sides = attributes.get(Sides.class);
    System.out.println("copies: " + copies);
    System.out.println("media: " + media);
    System.out.println("mediaPrintableArea: " + mediaPrintableArea);
    System.out.println("mediaTray: " + mediaTray);
    System.out.println("orientationRequested: " + orientationRequested);
    System.out.println("sides: " + sides);

    attributes.remove(Sides.class);
    attributes.add(Sides.DUPLEX);

    job.print();
}
```

With the example above I got this output:

```
media: iso-a4
orientation-requested: portrait
media-printable-area: (25.4,25.4)->(159.2,246.2)mm
copies: 1

copies: 1
media: iso-a4
mediaPrintableArea: (25.4,25.4)->(159.2,246.2)mm
mediaTray: null
orientationRequested: portrait
sides: null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  that worked. I see that the Properties button on the Print Dialog disabled. Any idea on how to have it enabled?

Comment: May be because there is nothing to print. Did you call `job.setPrintable(...)` ? See [A Basic Printing Program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html).

Comment: For me (with my printer, on Windows) the Properties button in Print Dialog is enabled and works fine. May be your printer does not support any properties.

Comment: what if the Printing is coming from Ms. Excel... would it be possible to trace the info by using java? I wonder to get the 'number of copies' detail but out of luck... @ThomasFritsch